# Java excute Mongodb Raw Query

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query, spring-data-mongodb

Is there a way to execute MongoDB query in the form of SQL, similar to JDBC Statement.

e.g. I would like to execute query `db.products.find({"_id" : ObjectId("56eadecd69eefd335e8d8f0d")}).pretty();` as it is using Java. Could you please share some example? I tried below code

```
BasicDBObject obj = new BasicDBObject();
obj.append("$eval", query);
CommandResult cr = mongoTemplate.executeCommand(obj);
String createdBy = cr.getString("createdBy" );
```

but it returns error

```
{ "serverUsed" : "xxxxx" , "ok" : 0.0 , "errmsg" : "not authorized on shopchatdb to execute command { $eval: \"db.products.find({\"_id\" : ObjectId(\"56eadecd69eefd335e8d8f0d\")}).pretty()\" }" , "code" : 13}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [Jongo](http://jongo.org/) library, where the query syntax would be exactly similar to the query in mongo shell.

Jongo equivalent for your query would be:

```
DB db = new MongoClient().getDB("dbname");

Jongo jongo = new Jongo(db);
MongoCollection products = jongo.getCollection("products");

MongoCursor<Product> all = friends.find("{"_id" : ObjectId("56eadecd69eefd335e8d8f0d")}").as(Product.class);

//Product.java is your POJO
```